# how to reduce SSRS report loading time

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report with 2 date parameters.
for large date range report loading time is very large.
How can I reduce this loading time ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By optimizing your query with indexes.

Comment: details on where the time is being used would be helpful. Is the query or stored procedure... possibly in the postback of the report.

Comment: @SFrejofsky time is used in the following query: select OrderTrackDate,SUM(OrderTotal) as T,COUNT(*) as cnt
from OrderInfo
where OrderTrackDate Between '3/1/2014' AND '4/1/2015'
group by OrderCustName,OrderTrackDate

Answer (score 0):

2 things you can do.

1.declare and set local parameters to take the place of your ssrs parameters (if they are provided) to avoid parameter sniffing.

2. Like @Tab Alleman said. Indexes.

There really isnt a whole lot of room to optimize your query as it is fairly basic.

Comment: date range is variable. I cant declare and set local parameters with a fixed date range.

Comment: You don't set them to fixed dates you set the local variable equal to the stored procedure parameter that is being feed by the report.    `delcare @localvar datetime = @storedprocedureparam`   or use and declare and set if you are working in an older version of ssms